# Sprite/Object/Room limits in GameMaker 8.1?

Tags: sprites, game-maker, objects

I know about GameMaker Studio’s limitations for sprites, objects, rooms, and other assets (https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/230407528-GameMaker-Studio-2-Trial-Limitations), but I can’t find anything about if there are similar limitations in GameMaker 8.1, which I also have on my computer. What are the limits for sprite, object, background, and room count in the Lite and Standard versions of GameMaker 8.1, if there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GM 8.1 Lite has a lot of limitations. And there is no any reason to use it.

Documentation says:

> Standard Edition contains considerably more functionality and does not display any logos or popup messages. More precisely, Standard Edition has the following additional functionality:
>
> - No GameMaker logo is shown when running a game.
> - No GameMaker TV logo in the corner of a game.
> - No GameMaker advert screen on exit.
> - No regular popups remind you of upgrading.
> - You can use color blended sprites, which can be used for many special effects and easy shadows.
> - There are additional options in the sprite and image editors.
> - There are additional actions for e.g. CD music, rotated text, and colorized shapes.
> - You can use special sound effects and positional sound.
> - You can create splash screens with movies, images, webpages, texts, etc.
> - There is a particle system to create explosions, fireworks, flames, rain, and other effects.
> - A number of advanced drawing functions are available, for example colorized text and textured polygons.
> - It is possible to create 3D games using functions for 3D graphics.
> - It is possible to create multiplayer games that can be played over a network.
> - You can define your own room transitions.
> - You can use functions to create, load, and modify resources (sprites, backgrounds, etc.) while the game is running.
> - There is a collection of functions to create and use data structures.
> - There are functions for motion planning.
> - You get the possibility to include additional files in the game executables that can be used when the game is run.
> - Standard Edition can be easily extended using extension package. These can be made by everybody and will in general be provided free of charge.
> - Three such extension packages are included adding many room transitions, windows dialogs, and printing facilities.
> - You can define your own trigger events.
> - You can export and import resources, which makes it easier to collaborate on games.

Comment: 1) I am asking about sprite limits for _both_ versions. 2) I am looking for information on sprite limits, not why the Standard version is better (though I do not dispute it is — read on though). 3) GM 8.1 Standard is no longer available for sale. I installed GM through a leftover installer I had. GM Studio is undesirable because of its even more severe limitations on sprites, rooms etc., as well as the fact that while GM 8.1 is usable on my Mac using WINE but GM Studio is not. This makes GM 8.1 Lite the best option for me, because I prefer GameMaker's interface to other software.

Comment: 1,2) Don't read it as "GM8.1 Standard has...", read it as "GM8.1 Lite has not...". There are no any other limits. 3) GMS available and has native version for Mac.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I just checked and your answer is correct.